# JavaScript / TypeScript Framework that Supports Stream Processing Akka Style

Tags: typescript, stream

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to port a "simple" processing stream context from Scala/Akka to Typescript equivalent that includes parallel processing and asynchronicity via promises.

Assuming a straight forward stream, here some pseudo code from Akka with some simple comments.

```js
Source.from(GooglePubSubSubscription) // read from 
  .filter(validateMessage) 
  .map(convertMessagePayload) 
  .mapAsync(4)(callOtherApi) // the API, max 4 concurrent calls active at all times
  .map(acknowledgeMessageOnPubSub) // on success of third party API ack message on pubsub
```

The problem with frameworks like async or p-limit is that the workload is not known in advance, as it is a continuous stream. So needs additional work around error/retry handling and managing input/output.

I tried rxjs, where I failed ultimately due to back pressure support across splitting/joining the stream. And I could find find a stage that had a limited concurrency option.

I ended up writing a minimal implementation on top of [async's queue](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue) using the callbacks for drain, etc. but /feels/ to me that this should be a solved problem and there is an existing library in JS that can model these kind of streams.

Any recommendations?